# Show NextGen Gallery title

Tags: php, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I have a problemen for a while and im not finding the right solution. A lot of solutions are old and dont work in my situation.

I have a wordpress website with the nextgen gallery plugin installed. Now i want to display the gallery name on top of the gallery page.

A option im using on other pages is this:  $gallery->title

But this isn't working.

My website is [here](http://www.octest.nl) and the gallery is [here](http://www.octest.nl/gallerij/nggallery/gallery-pagina/Vrijdag/)

The file i'm working is located in this path(index.php):
/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_gallery/templates/thumbnails

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you declare the global variable for NextGen?

Answer (score 1):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-it-possible-to-display-title-on-gallery-page

Thank goodness for awesome people! (k33f)

```
 <?php
 // This develish little snippet is responsible for displaying the Gallery title when viewing a gallery thumbnail page
 global $wpdb;
 $gal_id = $displayed_gallery->container_ids;
 $myrow = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_ngg_gallery WHERE gid = $gal_id[0]");
 echo '<h1 style="padding-bottom: 20px;">' . $myrow->title . '</h1>';
 ?>
```